# Why do I get this "unreachable statement" error?

Tags: java

I am converting a roman numeral input to it's integer value. In my convertChar method, I keep getting an error that it is an unreachable statement whenever I add a break statement in to the code. I don't know why this is. I'm a new student and I must have done something wrong and I was hoping maybe someone can show me what I did wrong and how to fix it. It must have something to do with the way I set the methods up right? I still get confused on what variables to input so maybe I messed up there but I'm not experienced enough to know exactly what I did wrong. Here is everything I have:

```
public class RomanNumeralConverter {

public int romanInput() {       
    return convert(getUserInput());
}   

public String getUserInput() {

    Scanner numberInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a roman numeral in uppercase: ");
    String userInput = numberInput.next();
    numberInput.close();
    return userInput;
}

public int convert (String userInput) {
    int result = 0;
    int subtractamount = 0;
    int x = userInput.length();
    while(x != 0) {
    char romanConvert = userInput.charAt(x);
        if(x >= 1) {
        if(convertChar(romanConvert) >= convertChar(userInput.charAt(x - 1))) {
        subtractamount += convertChar(userInput.charAt(x - 1));
    }
}
    result += convertChar(romanConvert);
    x--;

}
result -= subtractamount;
return result;

}

public static char convertChar(char value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 'I':
            return 1;
            break;
        case 'V':
            return 5;
            break;
        case 'X':
            return 10;
            break;
        case 'L':
            return 50;
            break;
        case 'C':
            return 100;
            break;
        case 'D':
            return 500;
            break;
        case 'M':
            return 1000;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid character!");
            return 0;
            break;
}
    return value;

}

public void printValue() {
    System.out.println(romanInput());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RomanNumeralConverter().printValue();
}
}
```

Comment: The switch statement will _always_ return a value, meaning that `return value` will never be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in your switch statement. You can minimize this occurring elsewhere by attempting to have methods return only once (which i think is best practice)

```
public static char convertChar(char value) {
    char result;
    switch (value) {
        case 'I':
            result = 1;
            break;
        case 'V':
            result = 5;
            break;
        case 'X':
            result = = 10;
            break;
        case 'L':
            result = 50;
            break;
        case 'C':
            result = 100;
            break;
        case 'D':
            result = 500;
            break;
        case 'M':
            result = 1000;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid character!");
            result = 0;
            break;
                   }
        return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, it is a compile error to have statements that will never be reached while execution. In your case, the break statement will never be reached as there is a return statement above it. Also that last return statement will never be reached as you already would have returned in any case by the end of the switch block.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `switch` statement.

A `default` case can be thought of like the `else` in an `if-else` statement; it will *always* execute if no other condition in the `switch` is satisfied.  If you are performing a `return` (or `throw`) inside of a `default` case, any code that follows after that will not be reachable.

You have two options:

- Change the `return` statements to only assign a value to `result` instead, meaning that there's only one point of return from your code, or
- Remove the `return result` from after your `switch`.